# will cache jclass in native code prevent the class been unloaded

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

According to https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html:

> The class references, field IDs, and method IDs are guaranteed valid until the class is unloaded. Classes are only unloaded if all classes associated with a ClassLoader can be garbage collected

if I keep a global reference of the class, will it guarantee the class never been unloaded?

```
static jclass g_classMyClass;

jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *pJVM, void *reserved)
{
    JNIEnv *pEnv;
    if (pJVM->GetEnv((void**)&pEnv, JNI_VERSION_1_6) != JNI_OK) {
        return -1;
    }

    jclass classMyClass = pEnv->FindClass("com/example/MyClass");
    g_classMyClass = (jclass)pEnv->NewGlobalRef(classMyClass);

    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, if you use the default stuff rather than play with class loaders, a reference to any method or field of `MyClass` from the other classes of your application is enough to prevent unloading of `MyClass`; just do not bother.

What can happen in practice is that a process is killed and restarted, and in this case all static variables will get set to their initial values (this is why Activities use Bundles rather than static variables to pass data to themselves in the future).